# Python Violin Plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

How can I do violin plots like you can in R using `ggplot2`? In `ggplot2` you can create nice violin plots like:

```
ggplot(dat,aes(value,prob)) + 
geom_violin() + 
geom_jitter(alpha=0.1) + 
scale_y_log10() +
labs(x="test values", y="prob")
```

and you can obtain nice plots like this: [image]

How can I do the same in Python? I've looked at `matplotlib.pyplot.violinplot` but was not able to get anything similar to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using seaborn (note this is using the development version; things work a little different in the current release, but does do violinplots):

```
sns.violinplot(x=value, y=prob, inner=None, color="white", cut=0)
sns.stripplot(x=value, y=prob, jitter=.3,  color="black", alpha=.1, size=4)
```

[image]

The functions both return the matplotlib axes object, and you can do `ax.set_yscale("log")` on that object to use a log axis. Note that this sets the scale *after* fitting the KDE (I'm not sure what ggplot does).

Comment: I think a link to http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/index.html would benefit this post - I'm not sure that seaborn is a library that is hugely well known, although it seems very appropriate here.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I wasn't able to get your code to work, it seems sns.violinplot requires a dataframe rather than x, y values. How does one go about setting it up?

Comment: This is one is nice too: http://pyinsci.blogspot.com/2009/09/violin-plot-with-matplotlib.html